# If $G$ is abelian group and $a, b\in G$ with finite orders $m$ and $n$, then there exists a element in $G$ whose order is $mn$.

Tags: group-theory

Clearly $(ab)^{mn} = a^mb^n = e$ but I'm struggling with showing that $ab$ is indeed of order $mn$.

I know there is a more general result (under the same conditions, there exists a element in $G$ whose order is $lcm(m,n)$), and I know how to reduce it to the particular case in question, but I don't know what to do with this case. Also I found question on MSE of this general case but none have answers that proves the case in question so I think this is not a duplicate. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assume $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Assume WLOG $m<n$.

Suppose there is a smaller power $k$ such that $(ab)^k = e$. Note that
$$
e = (ab)^k = a^k b^k 
$$
and now clearly $k \ge m$ so we can uniquely write $k = cm+d$ with $0 \le b < m$ and then $a^k = a^d$. Similarly you get $k = hn+g$ so $b^k=c^g$ hence
$$
e = (ab)^k = a^k b^k = a^d b^g
$$
which $0 \le d<m$ and $0 \le g < n$.

Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ the orbits of $a,b$ are disjoint, so we must have $a^d=e=b^g$. Since $d<m$ and $g<n$ we must have $d=g=0$...

Comment: I don't see why clearly $k\ge m$. If $k<m$ then $k$ is also smaller than $n$ and so both $a^k$ and $b^k$ can't equal $e$ but I don't know how to imply $a^kb^k \ne e$ from this.

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ the orbits of $a,b$ are disjoint, so we must have $a^k=e=b^k$. By definition, $m$ is the smallest positive integer solution to $a^x=e$, thus $k \ge m$.

Answer (score 6):

That's wrong in general. If $G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2\}$ then $1,2$ are of order $3$, yet there is no element of order $9$.

Comment: My guess is that there is another assumption that $n,m$ are co-prime. In this case you can show that $ab$ is of order exactly $nm$.